# WordPress: Group posts by month?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

is there a way to do this ?

```
August 2009
11 Title of the post of the 11th day of August
15 Title of other post of the 15th day of August
20 Title of another post of the 20th day of August

July 2009
4 Title of the post of the 4th day of July
7 Title of other post of the 7th day of July
15 Title of another post of the 15th day of July
```

i need group this post by custom metabox `evmeta_test_textdate`

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$format_of_date = 'Y/m/d';
$oldest = date($format_of_date, strtotime('-30 days'));
$args=array(
  'meta_key'=> 'evmeta_test_textdate',
  'meta_value'=> $oldest,
  'meta_compare'=> '>=',
  'post_type' => 'upg',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'paged' => $paged,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for Wordpress is to handle dates by publication date and query in the following format:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => 2012,
            'month' => 12,
            'day'   => 12,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Is there a particular reason why should you handle dates by custom meta?

Comment: i need to get the post from custom meta, because this post for event

Comment: Independently of what your post is, it still has a WP date. Check out this post: http://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/custom-post-types-events-pt1/

Comment: i need for all month of year ,,, not one month only !! i need for (1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 12 )